# The name of the gum part on the camera body for replacement

Tags: nikon, nikon-d90, body

What do you call this gum part on the back side of the camera body where you hold your thumb at?

[image: Nikon D90 body with a separated gum part]

My camera is a 5-year-old Nikon D90 and I have used it in many extreme situations without taking care after the body much. After the recent mountain trip, the glue which used to bond the gum part to the body has dissolved under heat or dust or both, and the gum part keeps falling off the camera. The gum has also extended due to temperature fluctuations and the part does not fit into the old place any more. I cannot hold the camera comfortably. The conclusion is: I need a replacement for the gum part.

I can't explain my problem clearly because I do not know the name of the part in question. What is it called? Has anyone had a similar problem? Are these parts for sale from Nikon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the part you're looking for: http://shop.nikonusa.com/store/nikonprt/en_US/pd/productID.255748700

It's called a "Cover Rubber" and it quite cheap in the Nikon parts store. Have to admit, I never would have called it that...

Comment: Nice find.  Not what I would have thought either.

Comment: I'd have called it "Grip" or "Grip Rubber" myself...as that's what it is! :P

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the part I was looking for! Now I have to figure it out, how I can order it in Germany. The US-store delivers only inside the US.

Comment: ebay makes wonders.